# Date to Days conversion in PHP to warn

Tags: php

I wanted to see if there was an easy way to convert a date 05/14/2014 to then compare it to the amount of days left in a contract. For example, i want to get back an error saying 30 days left till 05/14/2013 is coming up please warn.

i have tried looking up stuff but it comes up with excel. i dont want to use excel =P

thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? You need to show some research effort in your question.

Comment: Ah sorry about that.  I tried to do a conversion like, 05/14/2013 -> just taking the amount of days into that date, but i would have to define each month, and add each day till that date , then subtract from the current day. =\

Answer (score 1):

```
$contractTS = strtotime($contractDate);
$targetTS = strtotime("05/14/2014");

$days = ($contractTS - $targetTs) / (24 * 3600);
```

This will calculate the difference between the unix timestamps of each of the dates and convert from number of seconds to days.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably look at PHP DateTime and DateInterval classes for help here.

```
$date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', '05/14/2014');
$date2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', '05/14/2013');

$date_interval = $date1->diff($date2); // returns DateInterval object
$num_days_diff = $date_interval->days;
```

Comment: I really like this code above. but im not sure how to include the DateTime::createFromFormat class  =\..

Comment: @Luis Use the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Comment: @Luis This is core PHP functionality.  No need to include the class, it is already loaded with PHP.

Comment: @MikeBrant thats what i thought, but when running in command line i get PHP Fatal error:  Class 'DateTime' not found      im running php-5.1.6-39.el5_8    and by the looks of it on google i need 5.2 right?

Comment: @Luis Is your PHP CLI installation older than 5.2?

Comment: @MikeBrant ah, i edited my post. yes =\ and i can only use 5.1 for now b/c of other reasons.

Comment: @Luis Wow that is unfortunate 5.2 offers a lot of improvements over 5.1 and its not like it is new (5.2 if over 6 years old and was end-of-lifed two years ago).  I would certainly look to get to a newer version of PHP ASAP. So it seems you might be stuck with using an timestamp-based approach like that suggested by Orangepill

Comment: yeah =\ sucks. i am locked in with 5.1 .. i used the other code provided and it works perfect. thank you guys.